# How to write custom Y-Axis titles on Charting control (Winforms .NET 3.5)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

I use the **Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET 3.5** to plot X/Y data. The Y-axis shows positive values for apples and negative values for oranges. The X-axis shows the time.

I want to place axis titles to the Y-axis. The *apples* title must be above the Y zero value, the *oranges* title must be below the Y zero value. The charting control can be re-sized, so I must update the position of the title appropriately.

1) How do place more than one axis title?

2) How do I control the location of the axis title(s) so that they are in the above zero ore below zero range respectively?

Comment: Which charts do you use? From the WPF Toolkit?

Comment: It's the [Chart control for .NET 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en) But I don't stick on it.

Comment: There are charts for asp.net and windows forms. I suppose you work with the winforms chart, I will edit and retag your question.

Comment: Probably you can't use WPF, but if you could I would try to solve this problem, because WPF charts have source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control does not support the requested feature. Only one title can be assigne to each axis.